# Calling template in xslt files

Tags: xml, xslt

i have created one template whic is like this:

```
<xsl:template name="loop">
  <xsl:param name="yeni"></xsl:param>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$yeni !=''">
            <span style="color:#ff0000">
              <br/>
              <xsl:value-of select="$yeni"/>
              </span>
                  <xsl:call-template name="loop">

                    <xsl:with-param name="yeni" select="substring($yeni,2)"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:text>I am out of the loop</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

i can call it somewhere and it works.But i want to call it from this code xslt design breaks down. Why i can't call in `<xsl:template match="//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine">` this template

```
<xsl:template match="//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine">
<tr>
<td id="lineTableTd" align="right">
<xsl:template match="/">
                          <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                            <xsl:with-param name="yeni">"hello"</xsl:with-param>
                          </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:template>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You cannot have an `<xsl:template>` inside an `<xsl:template>`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have  xml file which tags are in Invoice tag.i looping this tags with this template <xsl:template match="//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine"> .And one tag in Invoice/InvoiceLine have value like this aaa!bbb!ccc!.i must loop this value and parse it according to !. i try  this loop

Comment: As Tomalak says, the problem is **not** with calling the named template. It's the surrounding template `<xsl:template match="/">` that breaks your code, since it is located inside another template (matching `//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine`). That's not allowed. Remove the surrounding template and it will work (assuming your looping template does work)..

Comment: As a general recommendation: Indent your code properly. If all your code looks as messy as the two snippets above it's no wonder that it breaks and you have no idea why.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to show your current XML, and the output you expect, as that would make it easier to answer your question. Thank you!

Comment: hi i really want to do in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638715/how-to-split-xml-data-inside-an-element-using-xlst  i try another way to do above. i am new in xslt design sorry for my fault.

Comment: I would suggest you wait until your other question is re-opened. Your attempts (this is the second one!) to circumvent the hold are not helpful to you or others.

Comment: i you examine this  question you will understand that doesn't related with other question. i am trying new way to solve this question but Tim C only ask what do you  really want ? and i give link my other question.

Comment: No, it's not the same question as the one before. Except that when you are asked what is the real question, you answer that it's the same as the one before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your current code...

```
<xsl:template match="//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine">
   <tr>
      <td id="lineTableTd" align="right">
         <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                 <xsl:with-param name="yeni">"hello"</xsl:with-param>
              </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:template>
     </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem you have an **xsl:template** nest within another **xsl:template** which is not allowed. It should really look like this

```
<xsl:template match="n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine">
   <tr>
      <td id="lineTableTd" align="right">
         <xsl:call-template name="loop">
             <xsl:with-param name="yeni">"hello"</xsl:with-param>
         </xsl:call-template>
     </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note, you don't also need the `//` at the start of the template match either)

This would give you the following output though

```
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>"hello"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>hello"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>ello"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>llo"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>lo"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>o"</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000"><br/>"</span>
I am out of the loop
```

Possibly you need to change `<xsl:value-of select="$yeni"/>` in the "loop" template to just `<xsl:value-of select="substring($yeni, 1, 1)"/>`. It is also possible you don't actually need the quotations marks around "hello" in this instance

```
 <xsl:with-param name="yeni">hello</xsl:with-param>
```

You would only need quotation marks if you did it this way (to stop it looking for an element named "hello").

```
<xsl:with-param name="yeni" select='"hello"' />
```

As an aside, should you wish to split some text by a specific string, you can use a similar method. You can use the "contains" function to check whether a string contains another string. If so, you would use "substring-before" to output the first bit, and then recursively call the "loop" template using "substring-after".